# OutOfMemoryError / creating a background image with the dimensions of a view

Tags: android

Every once in a while I get a crash report for my app that looks like this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=18119KB, Allocated=15536KB, Bitmap Size=31040KB)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:695)
at myPackage.MyApp.MyView.onSizeChanged(MyView.java:46)
```

I couldn't reproduce this problem so far and have no information on which devices this problem occurs.

What exactly does "Bitmap Size=31040KB" mean? Is my app really trying to create a 30MB bitmap?
I'm creating a background image for a custom SeekBar component that should have the same size of the view (9-patch not suitable for my use-case). Here's the overridden method of SeekBar that produces the error:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w <= 0 || h <= 0)
        return;

    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colorpicker);

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,
                h, Config.ARGB_8888);

    // code that draws the image, left that out here

    BitmapDrawable bmD = new BitmapDrawable(output);
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, bmD);
    setProgressDrawable(ld);

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

Line 46 is the one where the bitmap is created.
The view stretches across the whole screen and has the default height of a SeekBar, so in the worst case the bitmap should maybe require about 80KB...any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Checked how often `onSizeChanged()` is called?

Comment: if onSizeChanged called many times, the previous bitmap you created not release, will consome some memory too, you can set Bitmap output to be member your class, and release it everytime if it's not null.

Comment: It's called exactly once, at least in the emulator and on my device. Even if it were called multiple times the bitmaps should be released since there are no remaining references. To me the "Bitmap Size=31040KB" in the error message seems really strange, almost as if this method is called with impossibly high values for width/height on some devices for some reason, but that's not really a satisfactory explanation for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Size bitmap width*height*4 = size. May be help you: [draw bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
Try this is code, may be it's help you;

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
try{
   Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,
                h, Config.ARGB_8888);     
   break;
}catch(OutOfMemmoryException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
   w -=50;
   h -=50;//or another numbers;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, that's how I estimated the maximum possible size that this image should have to about 80KB - should always fit into the memory I guess (as long as there is no leak, which there is none I think as you can see in the code) and is not even close to the 30MB that's reported in the error message.